# combining table and a button in a php table

Tags: php, html, sql

I am creating a table (in php) with the help of data from DB. I wanna add a button on the last row. I managed it. is it possible to make button press to load another php file?
my code is as follows. any suggestions please.

part of my code where i am getting data from DB and displaying it on a table

```
echo '<table >';
echo '<tr><th>Namel</th>';
echo '<td >' . $row['Name']. '</td></tr>';

echo '<tr><th>ID</th>';
 echo '<td >' . $row['ID']. '</td></tr>';

echo "<tr><td colspan=2><input type='button' name='more' value='More Data' ></td></tr>";

echo "</table>";
```

how to make it clicking the button will take me to another page.

Comment: Make an `<a href>` instead and style it like button.

Comment: i tried. Styling creates extra headache.  I have a css file for the entire table. i tried to use two classes. it somehow not giving any change!!!

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with javascript or jquery. Try to call javascript function on, onClick

Try the following

```
echo "<tr><td colspan=2><input type='button' name='more' value='More Data' onClick='redirect()' ></td></tr>";

echo "</table>";

<script>
function redirect()
{
    window.location.href = "page to which it should redirect";//url of your page
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. it works. But href page should have  .html extension?  seems like it won't work if the page has .php extension!

Comment: No it works for .php too. You have to give proper path of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
echo "<tr><td colspan=2><input type='button' name='more' value='More Data' onClick='redirect()' ></td></tr>";

echo "</table>";

<script>
function redirect()
{
    window.location.href = "page to which it should redirect";//url of your page
}
</script>
```

Comment: And what is the difference from another answer?